# How to update multiple values of json with where condition in redis?

Tags: java, json, redis, redisinsights

I have a JSON stored in redis. I wanted to update two of its value using a where condition for same key.
I am able to update for a single attribute, but how to update two attributes?

`JSON.SET TDSS "$.accounts[?(@.Code == 'abc')].feeAdj[0].feeAmount" "\"1000\""`

This is working fine for single value updates.
How can I update two values in JSON with condition of `Code == 'abc'`?

I tried `JSON.MSET`, it is not working properly.

Comment: Can you please explain what's not working with JSON.MSET?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that:

```
redis> JSON.SET x $ '[{"code":"abc", "val1":1, "val2":2}, {"code":"def", "val1":5, "val2":6}]'
```

Let's start with retrieving the values of two elements:

```
redis> JSON.GET x '$[?(@.code=="abc")]["val1", "val2"]'
"[1,2]"
```

Now, let's change the values of these two elements:

```
redis> JSON.MERGE x '$[?(@.code=="abc")]' '{"val1":3, "val2":4}'
OK
```

And retrieve the values of these two elements again:

```
redis> JSON.GET x '$[?(@.code=="abc")]["val1", "val2"]'
"[3,4]"
```

Note that [JSON.MERGE](https://redis.io/commands/json.merge/) is available since [Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/about/about-stack/) 7.2.